# What is the "best" way to fluidly reorder a JList?

Tags: java, swing, list, jlist

I'm making a swing based application where I have a JList that periodically get's updated with different orderings of the same data, gets infrequently updated with new items, and also infrequently updated with less items. I'm trying to figure out the best way to make this look good. Right now, I just call

```
JList.setListData(String [] data);
```

Which doesn't look too great, and it clears the selected items.

I want a way to update it that only clears the selected items if it was removed from the list, but otherwise keeps the same items selected, even if their index changes. I was looking into keeping track of which indexs are selected and then setting the selected items after changing the data but that sounds horrible. I also looked at ListModels and keeping track of my own but it seems that which items are selected is kept in the JList itself so that wouldn't work perfectly either.

I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Is the implementation of `setListData()` relevant? An [sscce](http://sscce.org/), such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10048030/230513) may be helpful.

Comment: use JXList (part of Swingx) which supports sorting/filtering on the ui level. Beware that all model-decorating solutions are invalid during notification of bulk modification (which often we can get away with as a more common chasnge granularity is single-item :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made you a working example.

I've used the `JList` like you requested, added buttons that resort, add, and delete from the list.

Anyways, hope this helps!

Cheers.

```
public class Test {

    private static String selectedValue = null;
    private static JList jList = new JList();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));

        jList = new JList(new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"});
        jFrame.add(jList);

        JButton rearrangeButton = new JButton("rearrange");
        rearrangeButton.addActionListener(new Test().new SelectedListener());
        jFrame.add(rearrangeButton);

        JButton addButton = new JButton("add");
        addButton.addActionListener(new Test().new SelectedListener());
        jFrame.add(addButton);

        JButton deleteButton = new JButton("delete");
        deleteButton.addActionListener(new Test().new SelectedListener());
        jFrame.add(deleteButton);

        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class SelectedListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            storeSelected();

            if (actionEvent.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("rearrange")) {
                jList.setListData(new String[]{"5", "4", "3", "2", "1"});
            } else if (actionEvent.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
                List< String> items = new ArrayList< String>();

                for (int item = 0; item < jList.getModel().getSize(); item++) {
                    items.add(jList.getModel().getElementAt(item).toString());
                }

                items.add("new");

                jList.setListData(items.toArray());
            } else if (actionEvent.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {
                List< String> items = new ArrayList< String>();

                for (int item = 0; item < jList.getModel().getSize(); item++) {
                    items.add(jList.getModel().getElementAt(item).toString());
                }

                items.remove(0);

                jList.setListData(items.toArray());
            }

            reSelect();
        }
    }

    private static void storeSelected() {
        if (jList.getSelectedIndex() > -1) {
            selectedValue = jList.getSelectedValue().toString();
        } else {
            selectedValue = null;
        }
    }

    private static void reSelect() {
        if (selectedValue != null) {
            jList.setSelectedValue(selectedValue, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/). How would you handle multiple selections? Edit: Sorry about the braces. :-)

Comment: This looks pretty awesome, I'll look into it and give it a whirl

Comment: I handled multiple selections by editing storeSelected() to save the array of values (JList.getSelectedValues()), then in reselect, I compute the index of each of these values and then I use the setSelectedIndices(int [] indices) to set them all. It's not the cleanest but it works. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 4):

It seems the standard `JList` has no methods to adjust the sorting (why on earth did they only added that to a `JTable` ...), but there is a [tutorial for sorted lists](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/sorted_jlist/)

Comment: That is a good article, it looks like its the right way to do this.

Comment: same problem as always with model-decorating approaches: during notification of bulk changes the sorted-model state is undefined ...

Comment: @kleopatra any good solution for that ? I see the JXList of the SwingX project provides view sorting but I am not familiar with the source code behind it